# R Shiny - Can a package be installed in-app once the app has been deployed to shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I would like to check if a package required by my app is available and install it if it isn't using something like:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage()

server <- function(input, output) {
  if (!require(ggdendro)) {
    install.packages('ggdendro')
    library(ggdendro)
  }
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The above works if I launch the app in RStudio but is it still possible to do this once the app has been packaged or deployed on shinyapps.io?

Comment: Maybe this comment is what you're looking for: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-use-local-packages-in-shinyapps-io/23709/4

Comment: Thanks @motch. I'm a little confused though - if the package is available on CRAN, how would I go about calling it in the app? Would I need to install the package?